# Quick question about smoke collision

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, collision

I'm currently making a low poly desert island for college, which has a volcano and smoke that emits from the top. I've set up a cone at very top facing down, which works as a collider, so the smoke plumes outwards. Usually it works fine, and I've baked it, but occasionally I'll play the animation and it no longer works. Any idea why this is?

EDIT: Here are two images showing what I mean. The first is how the smoke plumes at the top and the second is where it doesn't.[image][image]

Surely if the first one has been baked like that, it'll always be like that...? Unless I'm misunderstanding the purpose and function of baking... I only have to change something slightly and then it goes straight up like in image 2.

Also, when rendering out, or previewing the animation, is there a way of getting the smoke to play without having to see the Domain?

Comment: Screenshot plz 

Comment: Can you expand on 'no longer works'? What doesn't work? What happens instead? Please [edit] your answer to add more details.

Comment: It sounds like when you "change something slightly" you are not rebaking the sim. Anytime you change nearly anything about the sim you need to rebake it.

Comment: Does that include other simulations and other aspects of modelling? It seems like it's when I do *anything* I've been working on... Do you have to free the baking each time or can you click on Bake All Dynamics or Update All To Frame?